# How disallow Roslyn REPL to define a variable multiple times?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using the Roslyn REPL code in https://blog.jayway.com/2015/05/09/using-roslyn-to-build-a-simple-c-interactive-script-engine/. Here is my input:

```
int a = 1;

System.Console.WriteLine(a);
1

int a = 2;

System.Console.WriteLine(a);
2

string a = "3";

System.Console.WriteLine(a);
3
```

I wonder why variable 'a' can be defined multiple times here, and how can Roslyn generate errors like *variable 'a' has already been defined*, just as a normal C# compiler. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder why variable 'a' can be defined multiple times here

I believe it is one of features of the scripting dialect of C# that a variable can be redeclared across submissions. I'm not aware of anything you can do to change that.

Note that you can't do this withing a single submission. If you do, you get an error like:

> error CS0102: The type 'Submission#0' already contains a definition for 'a'